# How to serve from the root with express

Tags: express

I have a demo app that I just want to be able to serve from the root so I can serve files from node modules linking from the index.html file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html', { title: 'Express' });
});
app.listen(3000); //the port you want to use
```

structure

```
  index.html
  /node_modules
```

I know I can use

If I use `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

but I don't want to have to copy assets into that folder from `node_modules`

Comment: Why copy ? Why not just changing the path ?

Comment: Can you give example? @DenysSéguret

Comment: If you are storing static assets in `node_modules` you are doing it wrong. Move all assets to a folder and serve that instead of your root.

Comment: Example of what ? Of modifying the path ? `app.use('/static', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static')));` (from [here](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs%2Fserver.js#L150))

Comment: @SwarajGiri node_modules has all I need I can't be bothered moving the stuff, its just for a demo.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I dont want to use a static folder, just from the root.

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname))`

Comment: @robertklep please put in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve static resources that are located in the same directory as your `app.js` file, you can use this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
```

(`__dirname` refers to the directory in which the currently running script, `app.js` in this case, is located)